# Android form-"error-snackbar" implementation

Tags: android, forms, error-handling, snackbar

[image: https://material.google.com/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors]
[image: https://material.google.com/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors]

How can you implement such an error-display?

Behavior: After the form-input is checked for errors, a gray "error-snack-bar" slides open at the **top** of the screen. Google [Material suggests it](https://material.google.com/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors), but how can you actually build this?

(Btw.: I don't think, that a real snackbar (with top-gravity) is the right solution here.)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: It worked very well with my initial suggestion in my question, which I posted right now as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I created a textview with visibility initially set to gone. On error this textview becomes visible (with approriate error-text) and all other elements slide down automatically.